# How do assign a type of file to my app on Mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I try to assign a file type to my application.

In Info.plist I add:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>type</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>icon</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My Project</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSTypeIsPackage</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</array>
```

In Main.mm:

```
....
-(BOOL) application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename {
  NSLog(@"Opened by file");
  return YES;
}
@end
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  [NSApplication sharedApplication];
  [[[[Window alloc] init] autorelease] makeMainWindow];
  [NSApp run];
  return 0;
}
```

But when I try double click on the my file type, The app only open with the warn: could not be opened, MyApp cannot open file in format. Also the message from NSLog is not called at all.

Comment: Can we see the `@implementation` line that you've cut off from Main.mm? For instance, what is the name of the class that implements the `-application:openFile:` `<NSApplicationDelegate>` delegate method? You'll need to assign an instance of that class to be the application delegate after you've finished calling `[NSApplication sharedApplication]`.

Comment: `@interface Window : NSWindow {`
The application works without delegated method. 

I tried `-(BOOL) application: (NSApplication*)sharedApplication openFile:(NSString*) filename` and but the same, the message from NSLog is not called at all.

Comment: Apparently the application does not work without delegated method. Recommendation (again): Go with the Cocoa flow.

Comment: No, application works without delegated method. Delegate method it's just another way, must change more others in project. So I prefer to don't use it.

Comment: Try adding CFBundleIdentifier and set it to com.yourName.MyApp.  If your files have a unique extension I would add CFBundleTypeExtensions also.  May also need CFBundleName which you don't currently have.

Comment: This reference shows recommended info plist keys for Cocoa (page 18):https://images.qurancomplex.gov.sa/publications/documentation37/Publications3/1437_New_Contract/Study_Materials/Books/InfoPlistKeyReference.pdf

Comment: My plist have all: CFBundleIdentifier CFBundleName CFBundleTypeExtensions , CFBundleIconFile instead CFBundleIconFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following subclass of NSWindow should allow you to save a file with a unique ‘.jaf’ extension and then reopen the file into the app by double clicking on it.  The info.plist is not as critical as I initially thought; I did not alter the one created by Xcode.  Most important for this non-Document based app seems to be the calling of NSApplicationDelegate method -(BOOL) application: openFile.  The NSApplicationDelegate was added to the NSWindow subclass instead of having a separate AppDelegate as is usually the case.  When working correctly you should hear a beep when this method is called after a .jaf file is double-clicked; I couldn’t find the NSLog output.  To run the demo in Xcode first create an objc project and delete everything in the ‘main.m’ file and copy/paste the following source code into it.  Delete the pre-supplied AppDelegate class to avoid duplicate symbols.  In the entitlements set the App Sandbox to NO and set read-only to zero.  After the JAF app has been made, use it to save a file to your desktop with the ‘.jaf’ extension.  Then make a copy of the app (shown in the Finder) and copy/paste it into the Applications folder.  The next step is critical; right click on the file that you just made and use either Get Info or Open With to set the file to always open with your newly made app.  At this point you should be able to double click on the xxxx.jaf file and have it open into your app with an audible beep.

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface Window : NSWindow <NSApplicationDelegate> {
 NSTextView *txtView;
}
- (instancetype)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)style backing:(NSBackingStoreType)backingStoreType defer:(BOOL)flag;
-(void) buildMenu;
-(void) openAction;
-(void) saveAction;
@end


@implementation Window

#define _wndW  700
#define _wndH  550

- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename {
 NSLog(@"This comes from JAF : filename = %@.",filename);
 NSBeep(); // Listen for this.

 NSError *error;
 NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filename];
 NSString *fileStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
 if (!fileStr) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to open file %@", error);
  } else {
    [txtView setString:fileStr];
  }

 return YES;
}

-(void) buildMenu {
// **** Menu Bar **** //
 NSMenu *menubar = [NSMenu new];
 [NSApp setMainMenu:menubar];
// **** App Menu **** //
 NSMenuItem *appMenuItem = [NSMenuItem new];
 NSMenu *appMenu = [NSMenu new];
 [appMenu addItemWithTitle: @"Quit" action:@selector(terminate:) keyEquivalent:@"q"];
 [appMenuItem setSubmenu:appMenu];
 [menubar addItem:appMenuItem];
}


-(void) openAction {
 NSOpenPanel *op = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[op setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"jaf", @"txt", nil]];
 [op beginSheetModalForWindow: self completionHandler: ^(NSInteger returnCode) {
 if (returnCode == NSModalResponseOK) {
  NSURL *url = [op URL];
  NSError *error;
  NSString *fileStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
  if (!fileStr) {
    NSLog(@"Unable to open file %@", error);
   } else {
    [self->txtView setString:fileStr];
   }
  }
 }];
}

-(void) saveAction {
 NSSavePanel *sp = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
 [sp setTitle:@"Save contents to file"];
 [sp setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"jaf", nil]];
 [sp setNameFieldStringValue: @".jaf"];
 [sp beginSheetModalForWindow: self completionHandler: ^(NSInteger returnCode) {
 if (returnCode == NSModalResponseOK) {
  NSURL *url = [sp URL];
     NSString *viewStr = [[self->txtView textStorage] string];
 NSError *err;
      BOOL fileSaved = [viewStr writeToURL:url atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
      if (!fileSaved) { NSLog(@"Unable to save file due to error: %@", err);}
  }
 }];
}

- (instancetype)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSWindowStyleMask)style backing:(NSBackingStoreType)backingStoreType defer:(BOOL)flag {

 self = [super initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, _wndW, _wndH) styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
 [self setTitle: @"Test window"];
 [self center];
 [self makeKeyAndOrderFront: nil];

// ****** NSTextView with Scroll ****** //
NSScrollView *scrlView = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 10, 10, _wndW - 20, _wndH - 80 )];
[[self contentView] addSubview:scrlView];
[scrlView setHasVerticalScroller: YES];
[scrlView setAutoresizingMask: NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable ];
txtView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 0, 0, _wndW - 20, _wndH - 80 )];
[scrlView setDocumentView: txtView];

// **** Open Button **** //
NSButton *openBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 30, _wndH - 50, 95, 30 )];
[openBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
[openBtn setTitle: @"Open"];
[openBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinYMargin];
[openBtn setAction: @selector (openAction)];
[[self contentView] addSubview: openBtn];

// **** Save Button **** //
NSButton *saveBtn =[[NSButton alloc]initWithFrame:NSMakeRect( 130, _wndH - 50, 95, 30 )];
[saveBtn setBezelStyle:NSBezelStyleRounded ];
[saveBtn setTitle: @"Save"];
[saveBtn setAutoresizingMask: NSViewMinYMargin];
[saveBtn setAction: @selector (saveAction)];
[[self contentView] addSubview: saveBtn];

 return self;
}

- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender {
  [NSApp terminate:sender];
 return YES;
}


@end

int main() {
 NSApplication *application = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
 Window *window = [[Window alloc]init];
 [window buildMenu];
 [application setDelegate:window];
 [application activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
 [NSApp run];
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the code you posted but I was able to get the desired behavior with a few modifications.

I assume this is your window interface and implementation:

```
@interface Window : NSWindow <NSApplicationDelegate>

- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename;

@end

@implementation Window

- (BOOL)application:(NSApplication *)sender openFile:(NSString *)filename {
    NSLog(@"Opened by file");
    return YES;
}

@end
```

This is extremely odd to be using a window object as an application delegate. Normally, you have a controller object that owns and manages the window and also acts as the application's delegate.

In any case, it's still possible to get... well, functional behavior by changing the `main()` function to the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    [NSApplication sharedApplication];
    Window *window = [[[Window alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSApp.delegate = window;
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    [NSApp run];
    return 0;
}
```

There are two notable changes. First, your problem was that you didn't set the window instance to be the application delegate. Second, IIRC, you should never call `-makeMainWindow` directly; rather, that method exists so that you can override it if you wish. If you want to display the window on screen, you call `-makeKeyAndOrderFront:`.

Opening a file should display the logged line in console (if you're using Xcode 12.5.1, resize the log window if needed to workaround the display bug).

Under manual reference counting, I believe this would leak memory, since no autorelease pool is created, but I didn't see any of the usual warnings in console. Anyway, while this code works, it results in a fairly undesirable scenario. There is no main menu in the app so to quit it you have to use the Dock. The window created is also tiny and has no resizing capabilities, etc.

EDIT: An example project is at https://github.com/NSGod/OpenFile.

Comment: It is possible to create fully functional apps without an NSDelegate; I usually use an NSApplicationDelegate just because that's Apple's convention, but it is not mandatory.  However, I'm not sure that you answered the original question which as I understand it is the user is having trouble opening the files that he has created with his app.  In my opinion, that is because he hasn't correctly set up the info.plist.

Comment: Please you can give me an working example of openFile without NSDelegate? I tested with the NSDelegate method and it works, so my info.plist it's ok. The problem is that I have to change the whole project.

Comment: NSApplicationDelegate is a set of methods that delegates of NSApplication objects can implement. Adding <NSApplicationDelegate> on behind your NSWindow subclass and is very little overhead.  I don't understand why you say that this is going to cause you to have to change the whole project??  I'm afraid that without using this delegate you will be unable to use the method -(BOOL)application: openFile which is what allows you to open files into your app by double clicking on them.  It's a very small price to pay and is not an entire class.

Comment: @apodidae: The Info.plist appears fine to me if s/he wants to open the file using the `<NSApplicationDelegate>` methods like . The other way is to specify a custom `NSDocument` subclass in the Info.plist for a file type and let the NSDocument architecture handle opening the files for you. That will call methods in the `NSDocumentController` or custom subclass thereof. Using the document architecture seems out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: @NSGod Correct; the plist does have to be changed for Document-based projects which this one is not.  That's why I went down the plist path to start with since that's what I was used to.  However, in a regular project it appears that we can get by without changing the plist which was news to me.  This is the first time I have used -(BOOL)application: openFile and was surprised how well it worked.

Comment: @NSGod How does your GitHub demo open a file when it has no code to create one?  How does your app trigger the AppDelegate method?

Comment: OK, I understand!

Comment: After I changed the NSWindow class with the NSDelegate controller object, NSTextField no longer calls controlTextDidEndEditing. Before changing, NSWindow was set as a delegate for NSTextField. How do I set the delegate correctly now?

Comment: Add another protocol to your NSWindow subclass by adding a comma and the appropriate text field protocol .  Instead of just <NSApplicationDelegate> type <NSApplicationDelegate, NSControlTextEditingDelegate>.  For example @interface Window: NSWindow<NSApplicationDelegate,NSControlTextEditingDelegate>.  You should then be able to use the method -(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:  and the delegate for NSTextField would then become 'self'.